# UWP-xaml InkCanvas: Is there a way to deny painting on specific zones?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, inkcanvas

I am trying to make a UI prototype for a bus route design app. The intended behaviour is to **let the user paint with a brush over the streets, but *not over buildings***. The idea is to get something like you see in the image below where the pink line represents the route that the user just painted.

I am currently using a basic InkCanvas and InkToolbar in order to do this.
My problem is that I have no idea on how to prevent users from painting over buildings. I tried to create several InkCanvas, each one of them representing a unique street, but that's a very clunky solution. Should I stick to this "solution" or is there any other thing that allows me to prevent the user from painting?

[image: pink line represents the route that the user just painted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UWP-xaml InkCanvas: Is there a way to deny painting on specific zones?

Great question, for your requirement, the better way is that draw line in [`MapControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl?view=winrt-18362) with [`MapPolyline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#add-a-line).

If you want to draw the line with ink-canvas, You need to declare that the building is not available. and please check official code sample [scenario 8](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SimpleInk/cs/Scenario8.xaml.cs). When the stroke
cross the circle, it will be removed.